# How to get OpenGL-ES working on Raspberry Pi with SDL2?

Tags: raspberry-pi, opengl-es-2.0, sdl-2

I am trying to get OpenGL-ES working on a Raspberry Pi, but so far no luck. I compiled SDL 2.0.3 from source with this, as the version in Rasbian is missing Raspberry Pi support:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/pi/run/SDL2-2.0.3/ \
   --disable-video-x11 \
   --disable-pulseaudio \
   --disable-esd \
   --disable-video-opengl
```

The code below should create a OpenGL context and clear the screen to red. When I run the code, the Raspberry Pi is switching video modes, but the screen is turning black instead of red and the calls to `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and Co. return `NULL` which would indicate that something is wrong with the GL context creation.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengles2.h>
#include <iostream>

void print_gl_string(GLenum name)
{
  const GLubyte* ret = glGetString(name);
  if (ret == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "error getting string: " << name << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cerr << name << ": " << ret << std::endl;
  }
}

void set_gl_attribute(SDL_GLattr attr, int value)
{
  if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(attr, value) != 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL_GL_SetAttribute(" << attr << ", " << value << ") failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL_Init() failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  SDL_DisplayMode videomode;
  if (SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode (0, &videomode) != 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Error getting current display mode: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::cout << "Current screen mode: " << videomode.w << "x" << videomode.h << std::endl;

  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5);
  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 6);
  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5);
  //set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8);
  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
  set_gl_attribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);

  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Minimal SDL2 Example",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                        720, 576,
                                        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  if (!window)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  SDL_GLContext gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

  print_gl_string(GL_RENDERER);
  print_gl_string(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
  print_gl_string(GL_VERSION);
  print_gl_string(GL_EXTENSIONS);

  glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

  SDL_Delay(5000);

  SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gl_context);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to not be in the code, but in the library path. A simple `-L/opt/vc/lib/` added to the compile command line fixed it. Without that the compiler would pick:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2
```

While the right one would be (use `ldd` to check):

```
/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

Comment: Does this mean you're able to write 3D code that compiles to RPi-OpenGL-ES rather than X11-OpenGL?